# What does mean "Spectrally Modulo a Compact Operator"?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, compact-operators

I have found this:

Let $A,B:X\rightarrow X$ linear bounded operators. If $A$ differs from $B$ by a compact operator, then we have that $A$ and $B$ have spectrally equivalence modulo a compact operator. But what this means?

I think we do not have that if $A=B+C$, where $C$ is compact, then $\sigma(A)=\sigma(B)$. Think about $A=B=I$. So, I don't understand what means spectrally modulo a compact operator.

Comment: It might be helpful to include a reference and more context. One thing that **is** true, is that the *essential spectrum* is invariant under compact perturbations.

Comment: This is the paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.2192, in Theorem 2. As you said, it is about the essential spectrum, sorry. But what does mean a compact perturbation?

Comment: Any operator of the form $A+K$ where $K$ is compact is called a compact perturbation of $A$. The point is then that $\sigma_\text{essential}(A+K)=\sigma_{\text{essential}}(A)$. One typical occurrence of this is when $A$ is a differential operator (DO) of order $m$ and $K$ is a DO of order $< m$.

Comment: Thank you very much!